# How to loop the element has a certain class only in its children nodes?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

How can loop the element has a certain class only in its children nodes?

for instance,

```
<ul class="item">
  <li class="url">A1</li>
  <li class="limit">A2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="item">
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="item">
  <li class="url">B1</li>
  <li class="limit">B2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="item">
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

And I just want to select these two,

```
<ul class="item">
  <li class="url">A1</li>
  <li class="limit">A2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="item">
  <li class="url">B1</li>
  <li class="limit">B2</li>
</ul>
```

this code I am working on will loop each `.item`

```
$('.item').each(function(){
        var object = $(this);
        var title = $('.title',object).text();
        var limit = $('.limit',object).text();

        alert(url);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `:has()` selector:

```
$('ul.item:has(li.limit)').each( ... )
```

See http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/